# How Google Determines When To Enable/Disable Night Mode?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

### What I'm trying to do

I’m currently in the process of creating an application using [[image]flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter) and I’m at a crossroad. I use the Google Maps app on my iPhone and it automatically switches to *Night Mode* at some time during the evening. The problem is I have no idea which method is used to determine that time.

### How I've thought about doing this

I’ve thought of a few options to determine when *Night Mode* should activate, but they all seem inaccurate or partially flawed:

- Use the geolocation’s *sunset time* and trigger *Night Mode* then. See my edit about *dusk time* below.

  - While I think this provides great accuracy, I’ve noticed that the timing is slightly off: See the **Data** edit for time comparisons.
- Use built-in sensors/camera on the device.

  - While this *may* work, it’s intrinsically flawed since lighting varies based on a user’s environment. Continuously changing the theme between rooms will definitely annoy users.
  - I’m also not sure what sort of sensors are built into each device. I know the iPhone has an *Ambient Light Sensor*, but I’m not sure what sensors other devices have (Androids in particular).

As of right now, my best method is to use a combination of both: Based on sunset, devise some sort of algorithm that takes in the sunset time and a *time buffer* that uses built-in sensors/camera to determine when ambient light drops past a specific limit. If a device doesn’t have a light sensor, then I would simply fallback to the sunset time for the user’s geolocation.

### The Question

So my question remains that of the title of my question: **How does Google Maps *decide* when the theme should change to/from *Night Mode* on a device?**

Additionally (but not required): Does [[image]flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter) employ any methods to help developers easily accomplish this task?

P.S. I’m not sure which tag to apply for Night Mode/Dark Theme (or whatever else people call it), so let me know if you have any suggestions (I don’t think it’s necessary to create a new tag).

---

---

## Edits

### Dusk Time

As suggested by Herb Wolfe in the comments below my question, perhaps Google is using *dusk time* to toggle themes. I can definitely add this to my existing logic to make it more *accurate*. See the **Data** edit below for more information.

---

### Data

It's difficult for me to gather this data, so I'll slowly post it here when I get a chance. Sunset and Dusk times below are retrieved via Google (see **Sources** below). Average is the average between Sunset and Dusk times for that day. Theme times are gathered manually by me.

```
Date              Sunset     Dusk       Average    Theme
May 5th, 2018     8:25PM     8:57PM     8:41PM     8:40PM
May 29th, 2018    8:50PM     9:25PM     9:07:30PM  9:06PM
```

#### Sources

- May 5th, 2018

  - [Sunset time](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Sunset%20time%20for%20may%205th%202018%20in%20Toronto)
  - [Dusk time](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Dusk%20time%20for%20may%205th%202018%20in%20Toronto)
- May 29th, 2018

  - [Sunset time](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Sunset%20time%20for%20may%2029th%202018%20in%20Toronto)
  - [Dusk time](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Dusk%20time%20for%20may%2029th%202018%20in%20Toronto)

Comment: Could it be using dusk instead of sunset, for your first option?

Comment: @HerbWolfe Thanks! That does help center the time better by averaging time between sunset and dusk, but it’s one minute off. Could be an inaccuracy on my end, but I’ll try to collect more time data over the next week to confirm. I’ve edited my question to include your suggestion and additional related information.

Comment: @downvoters can you help me understand why you downvoted my question so that I may improve it? Downvoting a question without explanation doesn’t allow a user the opportunity to improve not only their question, but also the overall SO community.

Comment: @ctwheels As far as I know, Google Maps' code is proprietary, so we can only speculate on how they implemented it. That's probably why your question got downvoted—StackOverflow questions should be concise and provide a concrete problem to solve, not lead to open-ended discussions and speculations.

Answer (score 2):

> Additionally (but not required): Does flutter employ any methods to help developers easily accomplish this task?

Since Flutter 1.9 - at runtime, you can check `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness` - in any Widget's `build` method. This will return either `Brightness.light` or `Brightness.dark`, which essentially tells you what is the device's dark theme status (not set / set respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Just like you guessed, Google Maps probably uses a combination of data from the ambient light sensor and the time to determine whether to switch to dark mode.
As far as I know, the Google Maps code is proprietary, so we can only speculate on how they implemented it.

However, let's look a bit into the future.
Both Android and iOS recently introduced dark mode support into their apps and you can provide a `darkTheme` attribute to your `MaterialApp`, allowing it to automatically adapt to the users' preferences.
Sooner or later, Google Maps will probably also use this OS API, so your best shot at mimicking Google Maps behavior is to use `darkTheme`.

(Technically, you could also have a look at the bitmap data of the Google Maps widget and then decide whether it uses dark or light mode based on the average brightness or color palette of the pixels, but that seems like a very workaround-y way of doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an example of what Marcel already said in his answer. If you set the theme and darkTheme respectively, with their brightness values in your MaterialApp Widget, your app will toggle between light and dark mode based on what the device wants.

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/themeMode.html) is the flutter documentation on Theme Mode, which determines which theme to use (defaults to ThemeMode.system).

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
  ),
  darkTheme:
      ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark, 
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange)
```